# Jacoco agent does not measure any code coverage

Tags: java, maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

During the maven build process I start my app using the `process-exec-maven-plugin` and run Integration tests with Failsafe. Now I want to get coverage data from the application under test.

The problem is, that the coverage report contains all the classes of my application but no coverage data (0% for all).
When I append the jacoco agent to the failsafe plugin, it generates the code coverage for the test-classes which does not really help.

Any Ideas?

**process-exec-maven-plugin configuration:**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-importer</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <name>product-importer</name>
                    <waitForInterrupt>false</waitForInterrupt>
                    <healthcheckUrl>http://localhost:${jetty.http.port}/health</healthcheckUrl>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${java.home}/../bin/java</argument>
                        <argument>${failsafe.argLine}</argument>
                        <argument>-jar</argument>
                        <argument>
                            ${project.build.directory}/jars/app-${project.version}-shaded.jar
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <!--Stop all processes in reverse order-->
            <execution>
                <id>stop-all</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>stop-all</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Using the following Jacoco configuration:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-jacoco-service-test-agent</id>
            <!-- default pre-integration is to late for the process-exec-maven-plugin -->
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                <includes>
                    <include>de.myapp.*</include>
                </includes>
                <classDumpDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classDumpDir>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>report-jacoco-service-test-results</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/out/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The problem seems to appear only locally, for our build server this configuration works fine. No clue why - I will keep an eye on it.

Comment: It seems like it's not attaching jacocoagent.jar to the target JVM (Tomcat/etc). Once it's done, then your .exec file size will be populated successfully after target JVM (Tomcat) instance is stopped. Check this (for both Unit and non-Unit aka IT tests): http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom-it.xml

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the server was gone together with the docker container in "HW power off" style - there was no signal like SIGTERM on which depends output of JaCoCo (end of the JVM running in docker container).

When I add command "killall java" that docker runs inside the docker container and a small pause before the shutdown of the container, the exec file is alright.

Comment: Are you able to share the script you used in your container? I tried a similar approach and it doesn't appear to be working :/

Comment: I'm not working on the project any more but I plan to prepare working example in few weeks in the Glassfish project ;-)
This is how I did something similar for Payara (but without JaCoCo, I did not go so far yet)
https://github.com/dmatej/Payara/blob/PAYARA-4176-TestContainers/appserver/tests/test-containers/tools/src/main/java/fish/payara/test/containers/tools/junit/DockerITestExtension.java
and
https://github.com/dmatej/Payara/blob/PAYARA-4176-TestContainers/appserver/tests/test-containers/tools/src/main/java/fish/payara/test/containers/tools/container/PayaraServerContainer.java

Comment: Simply said, you need to give a chance to save data for JaCoCo when the monitored JVM stops working.